# Google doc ignore microsoft word shapes when conveted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am trying to convert a docx file to google doc format. The docx file contains images, text, tables etc, but when converted to google doc format it simply ignores all the shapes in it..

Microsoft shapes are not supported by google docs ? or what could be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Not all features on word is supported to convert. Rasterize shapes to some forms of common image and try convert again.